# Complex Numbers ( Find a & b )

Tags: complex-numbers

sorry i'm unaware how to write this in the propper form i've only just signed up to this great website today!

The question I've been asked is... if $z = x +i y $
find x and y when:

$$\frac{3z}{1-i} + \frac{3z}{i} = \frac4{3-i} $$

Thanks everyone hope you can help and apologise for the presentation once more

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions because they were closed. Edit the previous one to deal with the closure reason.

Comment: Generally when you have a complex number in the denominator of a fraction, multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate is a good place to start.

Comment: See my comment in your original question.  ... which is basically Doug M's comment.  So..i) remove the complex values from the denominators by multiplying by complex conjugate to get ii) some A + i B = C + i D where A,B,C,D or some combinations of x and y.  iii) solve A = C and B = D to find out what x and y are.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Apologise guys, new to this site i'm not quite sure on how to present things yet! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start by multiplying the top and bottom of the fractions by the conjugates of the denominators (e.g. $1+i$ and $-i$ respectively in the left hand side). Then you can group the real and imaginary parts together on the left hand side, leaving $0$ on the right hand side. Then you can equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides (if the RHS $=0$, then the real part on the LHS is equal to $0$ and the imaginary part on the LHS is equal to $0$). Presto! You then have two simultaneous equations, which can be solved.

Comment: Nit pick.  If you have a *purely* imaginary number (ai) in the denominator there's no need to multiple by the conjugate (-ai which is just the negative).  It is sufficient to simply multiply by i.  In this case i or -i doesn't make any difference but ai by -ai will result in an extra a in the numerator that will just factor out later anyway.  But it doesn't really matter.  It still works.  And if rulez is rulez it's easier to not make exceptions, I suppose.

Comment: @fleablood yes, I considered that, but it is nice to end up with $1$ in the denominator instead of $-1$. As you say, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: True.  I hadn't considered that we'd have -1 in denominator when 1 is nicer.  Also when it comes to teaching "multiply top and bottom by the conjugate" is a simple rule whereas "well, you don't have to if it's purely imaginary as it's just i but otherwise do the conjugate reducing" just confuses a novice and is really just a tangent.

Comment: Just by you saying the word conjugates you have jump started my memory on how to do this thank you! i'll have a stab and get back to you !

Comment: Thanks @Sam . I'm glad you've responded. Please share your work if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use, when $\text{q}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\frac{1}{\text{q}}=\frac{\overline{\text{q}}}{\text{q}\overline{\text{q}}}=\frac{\overline{\text{q}}}{|\text{q}|^2}=\frac{\Re[\text{q}]-\Im[\text{q}]i}{\Re^2[\text{q}]+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$

So:

- $$\Re\left[\frac{1}{\text{q}}\right]=\Re\left[\frac{\Re[\text{q}]-\Im[\text{q}]i}{\Re^2[\text{q}]+\Im^2[\text{q}]}\right]=\frac{\Re[\text{q}]}{\Re^2[\text{q}]+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$
- $$\Im\left[\frac{1}{\text{q}}\right]=\Im\left[\frac{\Re[\text{q}]-\Im[\text{q}]i}{\Re^2[\text{q}]+\Im^2[\text{q}]}\right]=-\frac{\Im[\text{q}]}{\Re^2[\text{q}]+\Im^2[\text{q}]}$$

---

So, in your problem:

1. $$\frac{4}{3-i}=\frac{4\cdot\overline{3-i}}{(3-i)\cdot\overline{3-i}}=\frac{12+4i}{10}$$
2. $$\frac{1}{1-i}+\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1+i}{2}-i=\frac{1-i}{2}$$

So:

$$\frac{3z}{1-i}+\frac{3z}{i}=\frac{4}{3-i}\Longleftrightarrow3z\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)=\frac{12+4i}{10}\Longleftrightarrow3z=\frac{4+8i}{5}$$

Comment: Not to be rude, but I think Sam would get confused by your answer.

Comment: non taken at all! Luckily i did get the same answer :D

Comment: oh and to add... 4/5 = x and 8i/5 would be y? i assume

Comment: @Sam I got $x=\frac 2 3$ and $y=\frac 4 3$. I don't see how $y$ would be an imaginary number.

Comment: No, you've to get the three to the other side by division :) and then the real part is $x$ and the imaginary part is $y$